# IntersectionObserver Flickering with ScrollIntoView

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to build a custom input that you can change its value by scrolling with IntersectionObserver and ScrollIntoView

The problem that I'm facing is that when I try to make the component controlled with a state it starts to flicker when scrolling.

I have the [example here in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-duration-input-forked-rhn2o3?file=/src/DurationInput.js), and you can see the input gets initialized correctly with the correct value, but when you try to change it.. there is a flickering at the beginning of the scroll event. also resetting the input by the button does seem to work correctly.

I'm not really able to figure out how to get the updates correctly done in each event since I'm very new to Intersection observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `threshold` value to `1` such that it will fire only when it goes out of boundary completely.

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const selectedEntry = entries.find(
          (e) => Number.parseFloat(e.target.textContent) === value
        );

        selectedEntry?.target?.scrollIntoView();

        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
            return;
          }

          !isFirstRender &&
            onChange(Number.parseFloat(entry.target.textContent));
        });
      },
      { threshold: 1 } // changed to 1
    );
```

Also please do as the linter says, and add proper dependencies for the `useEffect` hook unless when not needed.

Comment: Thank you! Updated it, scrolling works fine now but still hitting the reset button produces a weird behavior with the states :/ added some logs in the sandbox if you can check again, also another input added

Comment: So I moved your `scrollIntoView()` expression outside the intersection observer and it seems to be working fine. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-duration-input-forked-lxn79d?file=/src/DurationInput.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you might consider [react-intersection-observer](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer).
In my case, I was able to remove flickering by setting [option](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer#options) `triggerOnce: true`.